# super() function in python

Tags: python, inheritance

`super()` function helps in accessing the methods and attributes of a parent class, but in the code below, we are assigning the parent's attribute (`name`) one value and the child's attribute (`name`, `age`) another value. But I want to access the parent's attribute (`name`) in the child class, without changing the value. What should I do?

```
class Parent:                    #Parent class
   def __init__(self,name):
       self.name=name
 
   def show(self):
       print(self.name)
 
class Child(Parent):              #child class
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.age=age
 
    def showName(self):
        print(self.name,self.age)
 
child=Child("nin",12)
parent=Parent("ninad")
child.showName()
parent.show()
```

Output-

```
nin 12
ninad
```

Comment: This are *instance attributes*, they don't belong to any class, they belong to the *instance*

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are asking, what is the output you expect?

Comment: Child classes automatically inherit all the attributes of the parent class. There's no separate `name` attributes for `Parent` and `Child`.

Comment: Expanding on @Barmar's comment, it is the OBJECT that has the attributes.  The object only has one `name`.  Whether it was initialized by the parent class or the child class is irrelevant.

Comment: All attributes are attached to the instance bound to `self`, regardless of whether the method that does so is defined in `Parent` or `Child`. `Parent.__init__` knows how to set the `name` attribute, so `Child.__init__` doesn't have to.

Comment: I *think* you want to use composition instead of inheritance, but it's not totally clear what you're trying to accomplish. You want `child` to know who its parent is, right? That'd be a good case for composition.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of using `super()` is to provide the aruguments as *keyword* arguments, so that `Child.__init__` not only defers the definition of the `name` attribute to `Parent.__init__`, it doesn't even need to know the attribute *exists*.

```
class Parent:
   def __init__(self, *, name, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self.name = name
 
   def show(self):
       print(self.name)
 

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *, age, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.age = age
 
    def showName(self):
        print(self.name, self.age)


child = Child(name="nin", age=12)
# Child.__init__ calls super().__init__, which resolves to Parent.__init__
# Parent.__init__ sets the name attribute on the object
# Child.__init__ sets the age attribute on the object
assert child.name == "nin"
assert child.age == 12
```

---

Note the use of `super` in `Parent.__init__` as well. Just because `Parent` doesn't inherit from any class other than `object` doesn't mean that some other class that inherits from `Parent` (directly or indirectly) won't have one or more classes between `Parent` and `object` in its method resolution order. Consider:

```
class Something:
    ...

class MadeupExample(Parent, Something):
    def __init__(self, *, x, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

When you call `MadeupExample(name="bob", x=3)`, the call to `super().__init__` in `Parent.__init__` refers to `Something.__init__`, not `object.__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

> in the code, we are assigning the parent's attribute(name) a different value and the child's attribute(name, age) a different value

You are assigning the *instances* called `child` and `parent` different values, yes, but *within the **same** instance*, the attributes are the same value.

> I want to access the parent's attribute (name) in the child class, without changing the value. What should I do?

You already did. `self.name` in the Child class functions refer to the attribute from the Parent class since it is inherited.